# Active Directory problem with authentication

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, remote-access, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a problem: I have 2 windows servers - the first one has Active Directory with all the client's user names and the other one has vpn server. I want the clients to use the Active Directory to authenticate to the vpn server - is there a configuration to do so? Thanks

Comment: Is the VPN server a member of the AD Domain? And what VPN software are you using?

Comment: Integrated windows server vpn and yes its a member of the AD Domain